# How to implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvObjectDetection[]' to 'System.Drawing.Rectangle[]'?

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I got that code from emgu's site, I fixed some bugs, but there is 2 more, which I can understand:

```
Rectangle[] regions;
regions = des.DetectMultiScale(gpuBgra);
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvObjectDetection[]' to
>   'System.Drawing.Rectangle[]'

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: You can't assign an array of MCvObjectDetection to an array of Rectangles. We need more details, i.e. what kind of variable `regions` is and what `DetectMultiScale` returns.

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without seeing the context it's really hard to say. The error is obvious, we just can't see *why*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
MCvObjectDetection[] results = hog.DetectMultiScale(gpuBgra);
Rectangle[] regions = new Rectangle[results.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    regions[i] = results[i].Rect;
```

First, get the results as `MCvObjectDetection[]`, then transform it into `Rectangle[]`.